# want to know when the closure of onPreferenceChange is called in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I understand that the closure of the [onPreferenceChange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onpreferencechange(_:perform:)?changes=_7) is usually called when the value of the Preference changes.
I wonder why the closure of onPreferenceChange is called in the code below.

```swift
struct TargetedModifier1View: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: TargetedModifier1UIModel = .init()
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Text("MyView")
                .preference(key: TargetedModifier1PreferenceKey.self, value: self.model) // regist PreferenceKey
                .foregroundColor(self.model.color)
                .font(self.model.font)
        }
        .makeToRed() // apply modifier
    }
}

extension View {
    func makeToRed() -> some View {
        modifier(TargetedModifier1ColorModifier(color: .red))
    }
}
```

```swift
struct TargetedModifier1PreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: TargetedModifier1UIModel { .init() }
    
    static func reduce(value: inout TargetedModifier1UIModel, nextValue: () -> TargetedModifier1UIModel) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

```swift
struct TargetedModifier1ColorModifier: ViewModifier {
    private let color: Color
    init(color: Color) { self.color = color }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onPreferenceChange(TargetedModifier1PreferenceKey.self) { model in
                model.color = self.color 
            }
    }
}
```

```swift
final class TargetedModifier1UIModel: ObservableObject, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: TargetedModifier1UIModel, rhs: TargetedModifier1UIModel) -> Bool {
        lhs.color == rhs.color
        && lhs.font == rhs.font
    }
    
    @Published var color: Color = .black
    @Published var font: Font = .body
    
    init() { print("init \(String(describing: self))")}
    deinit { print("deinit \(String(describing: self))") }
}
```

In the above code, the model is only **created**, but it does not **change**.

In fact, at the time of calling view, the model was only **created** and not **changed**.

Why was the closure of the onPreferenceChange called?
Or is there something I missed?

I am sorry that I am not good at English.
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: It's not entirely clear for me what the issue seems to be, however, I've copied your code and successfully run it. The "MyView" text is red. I've also checked the whether `color` property of the model is being set and it is. Could you, perhaps, rephrase or clarify the situation?

Comment: @Baglan As far as I know, the "MyView" text should be black.

The reason is that the condition under which the closure of the onPreferenceChange is executed is known when the preference value is "changed". 
But, this code is only "creating" the model.
Therefore, I think it is correct that the closure of the onPreferenceChange should not be executed. 

However, when I looked at the results, the closure of the onPreferenceChange was called and the color of "MyText" was red. 
I'd like to ask why it works like this.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Essentially, this a question when `onPreferenceChange` is triggered. In particular, whether it is triggered on the initial drawing of the hierarchy. The outcome of your code suggests that is the case.

Comment: Preferences are propagated  "up the hierarchy", I think, the initial drawing of the `TargetedModifier1View` emits the preference, which is then picked up by the `onPreferenceChange` inserted by the modifier, which, in turn, updates the color and causes the redraw of the hierarchy.

Comment: @Baglan I agree with you.
`TargetedModifier1View` appears to emit preference when drawing. (or init)
I was confused because Apple didn't have a clear explanation for this.
Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I did one experiment.
'TargetedModifier1View' appears to emit preference when drawing or initializing.

```swift
struct TargetedModifier1View: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: TargetedModifier1UIModel = .init()
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Text("MyView")
                .preference(key: TargetedModifier1PreferenceKey.self, value: self.model) // regist PreferenceKey
        }
        .dummyModifier() // apply modifier
    }
}

extension View {
    func dummyModifier() -> some View {
        modifier(DummyModifier())
    }
}
```

```swift
struct TargetedModifier1PreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: TargetedModifier1UIModel { .init() }
    
    static func reduce(value: inout TargetedModifier1UIModel, nextValue: () -> TargetedModifier1UIModel) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

```swift
struct DummyModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onPreferenceChange(TargetedModifier1PreferenceKey.self) { _ in
                print("onPreferenceChange closure")
            }
    }
}
```

```swift
final class TargetedModifier1UIModel: ObservableObject, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: TargetedModifier1UIModel, rhs: TargetedModifier1UIModel) -> Bool { false }
    
    init() { print("init \(String(describing: self))") }
    deinit { print("deinit \(String(describing: self))") }
}
```

run execute the above code, "onPreferenceChange close"

This seems to emit preference when 'TargetedModifier1View' is initialized or drawn.

However, Apple's official document could not find any clarity on this.